# How to config apache server to use cgi program?

Tags: apache, cgi

I want to write a test cgi program in C++. But when I set the configuration file as follow:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "F:/workbench/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "F:/workbench/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options ExecCGI
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
AddHandler cgi-script .exe .pl .cgi
```

then write a helloworld program as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and compile it with g++ hello.cpp -o hello.cgi
when I restart the server and visit the cgi: localhost\cgi-bin\hello.cgi 
it didn't work.

Comment: having similar issues.  WHM/cPanel environment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an HTTP header to describe the output. The Http Header and Http body are separated by two new-line chars. I think your code will work if you include a simple header like "content-type: text/plain". In other words, try with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("Content-type: text/plain\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```